# Installed pyusb, still: 'ImportError: no module named core'

Tags: usb, python, modules

On my Raspberry Pi I installed `libusb` and `pyusb` via `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev python-usb`.

But running some Python code ([pyrow](http://www.newhavenrowingclub.org/pyrow/), to read data from a rowing machine) gives me this error at `import usb.core`:

> ImportError: no module named core

This error suggests that I did not install `pyusb` properly, so I did it again manually (downloading it and running `sudo python setup.py install`), but this did not fix it.

I think the issue might have something to do with the directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb`: on my Ubuntu laptop this folder exists and contains (among others) `core.py`, but the folder on the Raspberry Pi seems to be non-existent. `ls` in the parent-directory lists the folder, but mounting to it doesn't work...

How do I fix this issue? Do I have to use a specific version of pyusb on the Raspberry Pi?

- Hardware: Raspberry Pi model B
- OS: [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) Wheezy (build 2013-02-09)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please follow the steps and see if it works.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip  #if you don't have pip installed already
$ sudo pip install pyusb
```

Comment: 'sudo pip install pip' gives me "Requirement already satisfied". Upgrading it gives "Requirement already up-to-date". I also tried a manual install of pyusb-1.0 as Krzysztof Adamski suggested, but the problem still exists.
Could it work to do the above steps on a fresh install?

Comment: skip the step sudo apt-get install python-pi.
Just type sudo pip install pyusb which should work for you.

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. I meant 'sudo pip install pyusb' gives "Requirement already satisfied".

Comment: @A.Goossens: You should probably first uninstall `pyusb` you have installed previously. While it is easy for the package you installed with `apt-get`, it may be harder for the manually installed one.

Comment: Because i couldn't remember which versions of pyusb and libusb i already installed i made a fresh install of raspbian and used the steps from Stevelrwin. They worked! Now pyrow works like a charm!
Apparently libusb isn't even needed or is already installed by default.
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: For me, the issue was that I had pyusb installed for python 2, but not for python 3.  'sudo pip3 install pyusb' solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

`pyusb` library comes in two versions:

- stable (0.4.x)
- under development (1.0.x)

Debian distribution only contains `stable` version and this is the one that you have installed using `apt-get` command.

Now `pyrow` is trying to import `usb.core` which only exist in `1.0.x` version of the library. And indeed, `pyrow's` website states that it need's 1.0 version of pyusb. This is why you're having the problems.

So in order to use `pyrow` you need `pyusb` 1.0.x which is not available in Debian so you can't install it using apt-get. The easiest solution to this problem is what @Stevelrwin sugested - using `pip install` will install 1.0.x branch of pyusb. You might want to use `virtualenv` if you don't want to pollute your system with some libraries not coming from Debian packages.

Comment: Thanks, that makes the problem a lot more clear to me! However, the problem still exists. See comment at Stevelrwin.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, this worked for my on a Raspberry PI 3b+ for Python 3.5.3

```
sudo apt-get install python-usb python3-usb
```

after running that the code import usb.core worked

(Raspberry PI 3b+ - Python 3.5.3 - 2019)

Answer (score 1):

Eureka!  I have solved the problem on Raspberry Pi which has both Python versions 2.7 and 3.4.2 installed.

Step 1: Copy the python usb libraries from version to 2.7 to version 3.4.

There were two folders in /usr/local/lib/python/2.7/dist-packages/

pyusb-1.0.0.egg-info, and

usb

Those were copied into /usr/local/lib/python/3.4/dist-packages/

Step 2: Use easy_install to identify Python version 3.4 to Python installation tool called "pip"
   command line:  sudo easy_install-3.4 pip

Step 3: Install the pyusb library into Python version 3.4
   command line: sudo pip3.4 install pyusb

Now the pyusb library should be installed in Python Version 3.4 instead of (or in addition to) the default version, which is version 2.7

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.

I did fined the cause, at least on my machine:

Raspberry pi comes with two installations of Python: 2.x and 3.x, but the installation script of pyusb installs the software on version 2.x by default.

So when we try to use it in version 3.x the error: "ImportError: no module named core" automaticly rises.

I don't have a solution for now but do think it should not be to complicated to find.

Comment: Have you read the other answers this is not the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Run the below command in the terminal when u get an error like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb' in ubuntu 20.04":

sudo apt-get install python3-usb